# WebView calling setContentView bug

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-webview

Okay, since it usually takes about 2 seconds for my WebView to load the page, I decided to display a "Loading" screen for my users. I found a very nice library called Shimmer that displays an animated textview. When my webview begins loading the page, I call setContentView to the shimmer layout and when it's done I call setContentView to the webview again. The problem is that the WebView is blank when I call setContentView. Why is that?

This is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
            {
                // TODO show you progress image
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                Log.i("WEBVIEW", "Loading");
                shimmer = new Shimmer();
                setContentView(R.layout.shimmer);
                ShimmerTextView shimmerTextView = (ShimmerTextView) findViewById(R.id.shimmer_tv);
                shimmer.start(shimmerTextView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                // TODO hide your progress image
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                Log.i("WEBVIEW", "Loading Done");
                shimmer.cancel();
                setContentView(R.layout.webview);
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you are implementing the Shimmer wrong. You should not call `setContentView()` more than once.

Comment: @Emmanuel This is the only way I see possible to do it because Shimmer is a textview so it needs to be in its own layout. Take a look here: https://github.com/RomainPiel/Shimmer-android

Comment: Have you seen the example [here](https://github.com/RomainPiel/Shimmer-android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/romainpiel/shimmer/sample/MainActivity.java)?

Comment: @Emmanuel Yes. I don't understand why this bug is happening though. Could you help me?

Comment: what do you mean by bug? They code you are showing looks nothing like that code in the link I posted.

Comment: @Emmanuel What are you talking about? What the author of the library was trying to do and what I'm trying to do is completely different. I don't want a button that toggles the animation. And the author isn't even using a WebView. I don't understand why you keep going back to that.

Comment: I keep linking back to it (1) because you clearly do not understand how the library works. (2) because you clearly do not understand how Android works.

Comment: @Emmanuel Wow, well thank you very much for making a beginner feel like shit. What's the point of me coming to this website to ask senior guys who have experience for some advice, if all they're going to do is basically say "go figure it out yourself"......

Comment: First, you should understand how this site works. Then use a bit of common sense and treat people that are trying to help you with a bit of respect. I would have helped you if you were a bit more appreciative.

Comment: I believe that Emmanuel is trying to help you. For example, he said that it is not a good idea to call `setContentView()` more than once on a given activity. If you are going to ignore this piece of advice, why should anyone take the time to help any further?

Comment: @Emmanuel Okay, I apologize if I came across as rude. That wasn't my intention. I've just gotten a little bit frustrated trying to implement this. Will you please help me?

Comment: @Code-Guru Sorry, I didn't see that he had given an answer. I only saw the comments. Guess my browser was acting up or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are implementing the `Shimmer` wrong. You should not call `setContentView()` more than once.

You should do something like this:

1) Add a `Fragment` that contains your `WebView` and make it load the url.

2) Add a `Fragment` that contains the `Shimmer` `View` and start `Shimmer` after you inflate the `View` of the `Fragment` in `onCreateView()`.

3) When the `WebView` finishes loading, use an event bus like [`Otto`](https://square.github.io/otto) to let the `Activity` that contains `Shimmer` `Fragment` know to remove it.

Comment: I was updating the answer.

Comment: Okay, I have to go to bed now but I'll look into that tomorrow morning. Thank you so much for your help! Sorry about earlier.